# How to set a resize limit for a window?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Lets say I have a xaml for my window like this:

```
<Window x:Class="WavePoint_MVVM.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    FontSize="13" 
    FontFamily="Verdana"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WavePoint_MVVM"
    Height="{Binding SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeigth}" 
    Width="{Binding SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth}"
    AllowsTransparency="False"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip"
   <Grid/>
</Window>
```

Now I want to fix some sort of limit in which the user can't resize the window beyond it. Just to give an example, in Spotify app for Windows desktop, the user can't resize beyond a certain limit. This is the minimum I can get:

[image]

Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To force a minimum window size, set your MinWidth and MinHeight attributes on the `Window`:

```
<Window x:Class="WavePoint_MVVM.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    FontSize="13" 
    FontFamily="Verdana"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WavePoint_MVVM"
    Height="{Binding SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeigth}" 
    Width="{Binding SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth}"
    AllowsTransparency="False"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip"
    MinWidth="640"
    MinHeight="480">
   <Grid/>
</Window>
```

Comment: Watch out for `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"` option. If also set on a window, then setting `MinWidth` and `MinHeight` as recommended overwrites `Width` and `Height` (window starts with min dimensions).